# First Heroku, Ruby & Postgres App - Local Postgres Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have been following Heroku's guide to getting started with Ruby on Heroku, and have gotten stuck trying to connect to the postgres database.

When I run:

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

I am left with this error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"garrett", "username"=>"ruby-getting-started"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried editing my database.yml file but I'm not sure if I am changing the correct parameters:

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
# For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: 5

development:
<<: *default
database: ruby-getting-started_development
username: ruby-getting-started

test:
<<: *default
database: ruby-getting-started_test

production:
<<: *default
database: ruby-getting-started_production
username: ruby-getting-started
password: <%= ENV['RUBY-GETTING-STARTED_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Do I have my database.yml setup incorrectly or am I completely wrong?

Comment: try this command pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start , then do the db:migrate

Comment: Hey man, I tried running that command and ended up with this:

garrett@garrett-virtual-machine:~/ruby-getting-started$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl: Coordinator or Datanode option not specified (-Z)
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

Comment: The _Coordinator or Datanode option_ part of the message reveals that you don't have postgresql but [postgres-xc](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres-XC). Presumably you've chosen the wrong packages at some point of your install. Ubuntu has an unfortunate error message when psql is not found that can lead to that mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Daniel. I removed Postgres-xc and ran: 

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3

Now, I receive this error after running bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate    

could not connect to server: no such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PSQL.5432

Answer (score 1):

This is a common Postgres error that is basically telling you it can’t find the server. This can be caused by various reasons from not having it installed to a broken path from an OS update.

If you do have the server installed you could re install it through Homebrew or the GUI windows installer found at postgres.org.

Either way the fastest fix is to use a single package installer like Postgres.app for mac.